# PHP file_get_contents skipping characters

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have been attempting to parse a file. In Notepad++ it doesn't show a character between these two characters, it shows EOT: [Notepad Text](http://puu.sh/5JWnt.png)

But, php doesn't see that: [PHP Text](http://puu.sh/5JWxS.png)

Is there a reason PHP is not seeing this character? How do I get it to see said character and turn it into a line break? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the codes here instead ?

Comment: Where did you get the text from exactly?

Comment: PHP is seeing it, your browser isn't. Try a `var_dump` and view source. You can go as far as saving the response as text and viewing with a hex editor.

Comment: @DaveChen I dumped and viewed the source, there still isn't a character there :\

Comment: ASCII control characters have no meaning in HTML context.

Comment: @mario So that means there is no way for me to convert this character to a line break?

Comment: Added a bit more info to address that

Answer (score 1):

EOT is a control character. When output to a web browser, there is no matching glyph, so nothing to output.

If you output the ascii value of each position of the string, or the length of the string, you'll likely find that the character is still there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character

If you want to change EOT into a line break, you could likely loop over the string checking for non-letter ASCII values and replacing them with a return character. Then use PHP's nl2br() function before output to convert newlines into a line break.

Untested code:

```
for ($i = 0; i < count($string); $i++){
    if(ord($string[$i]) == 4)$string[$i] = '\n';
}
```

ASCII 4 is EOT, ASCII 13 is Carriage Return, better know as Newline.

Comment: Your loop is comparing chars against their numeric representation, which won't work. For simplicity: `strtr("\4", "\n", $str)`

Comment: True enough, Like I said, untested code. I added ord() to that loop which would convert the char into the ascii value.